# Remove street address label and * from required

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2.3

I'm trying to remove the street address label in checkout.

I'm using this:

```
unset($jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['label']);
```

And the text in the label gets removed the but red star * from required stays in the ::after in the label. How do I get rid of the star?

Comment: Where did you put these lines

Comment: @FarahS in the layout processor but it didn't work, look at the Answer for what i actually used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just putting after on display none.

```
&::after {
      display:none;
 }
```